# WPF PathListBox Items Orientation and Start position

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, entity-framework, xaml

How i can show Jan at top center location? And how to set orientation of items in anticlockwise direction? Currently first item starts at 90 degree, as you can see it is Jan and showing on right center. Then Feb is on right of Jan and so on.
[image: PathListBoxSample]

Here is the XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="RootLayout">
        <Ellipse Name="ellipse"
                 StrokeThickness="75" 
                 Stroke="Orange" 
                 RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"/>
        <ec:PathListBox x:Name="pathListBoxItems" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Height="100" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Width="100">
            <ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
                <ec:LayoutPath SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=ellipse}" 
                               Orientation="OrientToPath" 
                               Distribution="Even"></ec:LayoutPath>
            </ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
            <ec:PathListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="28" 
                          Height="75" 
                          Background="Transparent">
                        <Rectangle Width="28" 
                                   Fill="Green" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                   RenderTransformOrigin="1,1">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="6"></RotateTransform>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                            Margin="-6,-20,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ec:PathListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ec:PathListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: First - it's ugly (imho), consider not doing it this way. Secondly - you forgot to show source what produce such a thing.

Comment: Hi, please show the XAML (or code) you used to produce this.

Comment: You could rotate it all... but there should be a better way I assume